# Catch a Neo4j exception

Tags: python, exception, neo4j

I can't catch a ConstraintError exception.

When I run this:

```
try:
    tx.run('MERGE (:Person {{name:"{name}",country:"{country}"}})'.format(name=name,country=country))
except ConstraintViolation:
    pass
```

the exception is still raised.

I tried

```
from neo4j.v1 import exceptions
```

and also ConstraintError and ConstraintViolation.

However, wether I try to catch ConstraintError or ConstraintViolation I get this error:

```
ConstraintError: Node(5314) already exists with label `Person` and property `name` = 'SomeThing'
```

How can I handle this properly ?

Comment: Are you sure you imported the correct ConstraintViolation? Can you post more context and the output of the program?

Comment: Could you try importing like such ```from neo4j.exceptions import ConstraintError```

Comment: Still the same issue... :/

Comment: The interesting bit is ... that a MERGE should not give an exception at all (at least not on a constraint). Sorry for asking but is that really the location in the code where the exception is raised ?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose this node already exists (I use string literals instead of parameters, for clarity):

```
(:Person {name: "SomeThing", country: "Canada"})
```

and you make this request:

```
MERGE (:Person {name: "SomeThing", country: "USA"})
```

You would get a `ConstraintError` because such a node does not yet exist (with both property values), and yet you also cannot create that node (because of the uniqueness constraint).

#### Possible Fixes

- If you want to force the `country` value to be "USA", no matter what, this should avoid the `ConstraintError`:

  ```
  MERGE (p:Person {name: "SomeThing"})
  SET p.country = "USA";
  ```
- Or, if you only want to set the `country` value if a node with that `name` value does not yet exist, then this should work:

  ```
  MERGE (p:Person {name: "SomeThing"})
  ON CREATE SET p.country = "USA";
  ```
- Or, if you only want to set the `country` value if a node with that `name` value already exists, then this should work:

  ```
  MERGE (p:Person {name: "SomeThing"})
  ON MATCH SET p.country = "USA";
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found that the reason that the exception was not being hit was that the neo4j driver does not raise the exception until the session is closed.

It's not in the code above but I assume that you had previously opened a sesssion - something like

```
session = driver.session()
```

if you move your session.close into the try block then you should hit the exception

```
session = driver.session()

session.run("MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n")
session.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Person) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE")
try:
    session.run("CREATE (n:Person {name:'Bob'})")
    session.run("CREATE (n:Person {name:'Bob'})")
    session.close()
except:
    print("Error")
```